# ajax not sending data to index.php

Tags: ajax

```
$(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
    var no = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.show_more').hide();
    $('.loding').show();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'index.php',
        data:'id='+no,
        success:function(html){
            $('#show_more_main'+no).remove();
            $('.snne').append(html);
        }
    });
});
```

ajax not sending data to php im trying this echo $_POST["id"] but im getting Notice: Undefined index: id error also saying that 
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to jquery version above 3.0 to fix this problem.

**Or**

This solution only works for some cases :

Instead of `success` method use `done` method.

Replace `success:function(html){` with `done:function(html){`

**EDIT**

add this line in your code `async: true`. Like this :

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'index.php',
        asyc: true,//<---- insert this
        data:'id='+no,
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: again same problem